# How can I upload MP3's to youtube using Ubuntu?

Tags: youtube

I used to use Windows Moviemaker.  I am new to Ubuntu.  Is it possible to do this easily?  I am fairly techtarded.

Comment: plz explain briefly.

Comment: YouTube help page: `Since YouTube’s not designed to host files that are exclusively audio (.MP3, .WAV, etc.) or files that are exclusively images (.JPG, .PNG, etc.), before you upload, you'll need to combine audio and image files into a format that will work on YouTube.` - https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1696878?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to download a video editor/creator. The one I would recommend is openshot. 
Its much like Windows Movie Maker and you should be able to download and use it very easily. It can be downloaded from the Ubuntu Software Center for free.

Once downloaded you should be able to create, export, and upload your videos with ease.

[image: openshot]

Comment: In OpenShot this is really easy, especially when a picture is set on the mp3 file. Just import it as the tutorial shows ( at files ), drag it to the timeline and align it and click export. That should give you what you need.